How to Integrate React.js Frontend with Odoo ERP for Automated Data Entry
I have a live website built using React.js for the frontend, and we’re using Odoo ERP for our backend. Currently, we manually input data into Odoo from the website, but I want to automate this process.
Goal:
I want the data submitted in the React app (e.g., form submissions) to be automatically sent to the Odoo ERP dashboard.
What I’ve Tried So Far:
I looked into Odoo's XML-RPC and JSON-RPC methods for external API integration, but I’m unsure how to implement them in my React app.
I tried setting up an API endpoint in Odoo, but I’m struggling to link it with the React frontend.
What I Need:
Steps to configure Odoo to accept data from the React frontend.
How to make API calls from React to Odoo.
Best practices for securing the integration, including handling authentication.
I would appreciate detailed guidance, including examples if possible. I'm new to Odoo-React integration, so any help is welcome.

Hi Safa, Develop and use the controllers to establish endpoints and automate the process.  Maintain the type as JSON while creating endpoints.
For more please refer the following blog.
https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-connect-to-an-odoo-16-using-restful-api
